# Is my interpretation of Neural Network results correct?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, text-mining, measurement-error, model-evaluation

I use a neural network with a topology of 17-30-1 (sigmoid, atan error function, mse as cost function, 5-fold cv) for text classification. (It's closely related to a previous question [of mine.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22189/how-to-interpret-poor-performance-when-using-neural-network))

The input data is quite noisy thus I could live with not a "perfect" classification score, but the results I get are probably too bad (or even just random) and thus I ask for your opinion.

1. The training error is around 0.06-0.09 (MSE), i.e. in average each classification differs approx. 0.25-0.3 from the predict label; in this binary case with a class threshold of 0.5 this might be acceptable. What do you think?
2. The test error (MSE) is unfortunately around 0.20 sometimes even 0.25; i.e. the effective error for a test sample is around 0.5, which to me means that the network a) suffers from high variance and b) is just as good as random guessing.

I don't need a perfect classification, but the network should however represent the patterns of the input data. But with this results I think the neural network is more or less useless or rather the input features are crap.

Comment: Do I understand you correct: You have 17 input neurons, 30 hidden neurons and only one output neuron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would advise you to not use squared error but the cross entropy error. Squared error results from the assumption that your labels are subject to Gaussian noise, which will probably not be the case.

First, the output of your network should be a softmax:

$z_k = \frac{\exp{y_k}}{\sum_i\exp{y_i}}$

This is basically a logistic regression layer on top of the neural network, and gives you a proper probability. You can train that with the cross entropy error function (see [here for an explanation](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression))--the derivatives stay the same as for squared error and linear outputs.

Regarding the interpretation of the results: this is data set specific. If it is a hard task, that looks good. However, you should look at the acutal number of correct classifications in the end and see if that is good enough for your application. Anyway I think you will get better results if you use cross entropy.

Comment: You mean I should use Cross Entropy instead of ATAN as error function? I use mean squared error to measure the performance of the classifier (heatonresearch.com/wiki/Error_function). And in the binary classification scenario, is the output the probability of the sample that it belongs to class 0 or 1, i.e. a output value of 0.76 and the threshold at 0.5 means the sample belongs to class 1 whereas 0.31 means the sample belongs to class 0? Just to make sure, with SoftMax I need two output nodes instead of one.

Comment: I meant Cross entropy instead of MSE. And for softmax, you only need one output as well. (The probability is 1-p where p is the other probability.) And where you set the threshold depends on your application (e.g. use decision theory to find one) but 0.5 is typically right.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've asked for the output node amount because Encog, the nn library I use, always gives me 1 as the final result when I use one output node. When I try two then both nodes sum up to 1. Thus I tried with two output nodes. But if one output node is right  then there's probably a bug somewhere.

Comment: According to the author of Encog one output node always returns result 1, thus for Encog two classes are need when SoftMax is used.

Comment: I would consider using something else than Encog, since it seems to be rather limited.

Comment: What are your criteria? To me it seems to offer the standard NN functionality. Which would you recommend? (http://grey.colorado.edu/emergent/index.php/Comparison_of_Neural_Network_Simulators)

Comment: I roll out my own, so I have no experience with available frameworks. But FANN (http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) seems to be popular and has bindings for many programming languages.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to integrate it in my code. And I'm tied to Java. Thus I can only choose between Neuroph, Encog and Joone, as far as I could find out.